# "Unable to locate package" error during apt-get uninstall

Tags: nvidia, package-management, dpkg, cuda

I'm trying to clean out old CUDA installations by running

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
```

but I get the errors

```
E: Unable to locate package nvidia-diag-driver-local-repo-ubuntu1604-390.46_1.0-1_amd64.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'nvidia-diag-driver-local-repo-ubuntu1604-390.46_1.0-1_amd64.deb'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'nvidia-diag-driver-local-repo-ubuntu1604-390.46_1.0-1_amd64.deb'
```

I had deleted the deb file previously after finishing the install. I tried re-downloading the .deb file and running `dpkg -i` on it, but that doesn't fix the error either.

`dpkg -l | grep nvidia` gives

```
ii  nvidia-390                                      390.48-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.3                   amd64        NVIDIA binary driver - version 390.48
ii  nvidia-390-dev                                  390.48-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.3                   amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver development files
rc  nvidia-diag-driver-local-repo-ubuntu1604-390.46 1.0-1                                        amd64        nvidia-diag-driver-local repository configuration files
ii  nvidia-modprobe                                 390.46-0ubuntu1                              amd64        Load the NVIDIA kernel driver and create device files
ii  nvidia-opencl-icd-390                           390.48-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.3                   amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
ii  nvidia-prime                                    0.8.2                                        amd64        Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                                 396.18-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1                   amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
```

Comment: I don't think absence of the original .deb files should prevent package removal - however *presence* of files that match the `nvidia-*` shell glob in your current directory may well confuse things (you want `apt` to expand the `*` - not the shell). What does `dpkg -l | grep nvidia` actually say?

Comment: thanks for answering - I edited the question to show the printout.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are [globbing](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html) current files in the directory.  Instead of what you are running, try:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-\*
# or...
sudo apt-get purge 'nvidia-*'
```

The main clue that tells me this is the case:  You tried to remove packages named like `blah.deb` in the `apt-get purge` output.  Of course packages aren't **normally** named that way...

To see what I mean, check `ls -l` in your current directory.  You should see the .deb files you are matching.  If you wouldn't have those files in your current directory, the 'nvidia-*' would pass through unaltered to the `apt-get purge` command.

Good rule to remember: It's always best to protect your arguments with single quotes `'` to prevent unintended shell globbing and other expansions.